# How can I select a mysql row that has a status and 2 other variables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

OK, I don't know if I asked this correctly at all, but what I want to do is select a row based on the status and the user. So this is what I have:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM w_o WHERE maint_user = '".$user_name."' AND w_status = 'active' OR w_status = 'open' ORDER BY r_date";
```

For some reason it shows me some entries that don't have the maint_user = $user_name. I don't know why that is. It seems to work when I assign it to a certain user, but then when I re-assign it, it just pulls up all of the rows.

Any help would be awesome!!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap part of your `WHERE` cause in parenthesis to enforce operator precedence

```
WHERE maint_user = '".$user_name."' AND (w_status = 'active' OR w_status = 'open')
```

Comment: You are the BEST! That totally worked! I didn't know I could use () in code like that lol. It totally makes sense :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Bassed of what you have shown I would add ascending or descending to you sql query. Also wrap WHERE in parentheses.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM w_o WHERE maint_user = '".$user_name."' AND (w_status = 'active' OR w_status = 'open') ORDER BY r_date DESC";
```